# Nginx configration for my NodeJS app

Tags: node.js, nginx, https

I have a domain at http:/myapp:8008/service (only an example). I want to setup a reverse proxy using Nginx along with SSL capabilities for this server, whose requests are handled by a NodeJs app(listening on port 5505) located at `/opt/somefolder/myapp.`

I have Nginx installed and my NodeJs app is already running but am unsure of how to set up the server block for this server (app is not located at `/usr/local/var/www`) and edit the file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file to fit my needs. I have tried to edit it using configuration I've found from this site

> https://coderwall.com/p/hwkjba/install-configure-node-js-nginx-on-ubuntu

Along with this site to set up the SSL:

> https://www.sitepoint.com/configuring-nginx-ssl-node-js/

This has not worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) create file `myapp.conf` with this content:

```
server {
    listen 443;

    client_max_body_size 2048M;
    client_body_buffer_size 2048M;
    disable_symlinks off;

    server_name yourdomain.com www.yourdomain.com;

    root /opt/somefolder/myapp/public; # or remove it
    index index.html index.htm;    

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate    /opt/somefolder/myapp/certs/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    /opt/somefolder/myapp/certs/server.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;


    location @app {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8443;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @app;
    }
}
```

2) copy or symlink `myapp.conf` file to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapp.conf`

3) in nodejs app listen https:

```
var
  express = require('express'),
  https = require('https'),
  fs = require('fs'),
  path = require('path'),
  app = express();

var httpsServer = 
    https.createServer({
      key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'certs', 'server.key')),
      cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'certs', 'server.crt'))
    }, app);

    httpsServer.listen(8443, '127.0.0.1', function() {
      console.log('App listening');
    });
```

4) restart nginx

5) start the app using `forever` or `pm2`

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on the proxy_pass: https://127.0.0.1:8443;
My server is currently listening to 5505. Can i just set it to that ?

Comment: sure, I'm giving an example, it's not strict: "must be done like this". keep in mind that nginx will handle requests on 443 and proxy pass to 5505 so Your api or etc on node must be requested without :5505

Comment: Was able to initialize with pm2 and is accessible through https. Only issue is that since it is a self signed cert I get a warning on navigating to the site. But then again I would have to purchase a cert from a CA. Life saver!

Comment: Use CloudFlare and attach domain to it, it will defend Your app from attacks and also will give free wildcard ssl certificate signed by COMODO that You can generate and attach.